# How to open a specific URL

Tags: c#, process.start

I want to open an url with

```
Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_oOES_uKPI");
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to
> start process 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_oOES_uKPI' with
> working directory
> 'C:\Users('_')\source\repos\messingAROUND\messingAROUND\bin\Debug\net6.0'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Process.Start("fileName","arguments")` and in our case let's say you have google chrome installed so you Should replace "fileName" with chrome.exe and "arguments" with your url by example "google.com" and so on
So Change the below solution

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe","google.com")
```

**For Default Browser**

```
Process.Start("rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler https://www.google.com");
```

Thanks and have fun.

Comment: **For Default Browser**                                                                          
       `Process.Start("rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler https://www.google.com");`

Comment: Do I need to specify the location of chrome.exe? It throws back the same error. Otherwise the default browser solution - works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But, since when is it necessary to do this? Is a .Net 6 thing? IIRC, `Process.Start("http://example.com")` always worked in the past decade.